# javassist, get second param of doGet method

Tags: java, spring, javassist

i inject my code into `doGet` method

```
val replace = "" +
  "  System.out.println(\"[before] " + className + "\");" +
  "  $proceed($$);" +
  "  try{System.out.println(\"$args[2] = \" + $args[1].toString());}catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(\"ERROR\");}"
  "  System.out.println(\"[after] " + className  + "\");".stripMargin
```

Here i am getting second param and i expect that param will be instance of HttpServletResponse class, but i see following class

```
org.springframework.security.web.context
.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper@398ce9f7
```

Behind action is in DefaultServlet, FrameworkServlet

What is wrong with my reality?

Comment: That is an instance of `HttpServletResponse` a very specific subclass but it is an instance nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpServletResponse` is [an interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html), so there can be anything there that correctly inmplements the given interface. As you are in Spring, the framework is using its own implementation, as you can see from `.toString` mehotd, it is a [`SaveToSessionResponseWrapper`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/context/HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java) class.

On second link you can find a exactly place there is the substitution goes:

```
SaveToSessionResponseWrapper wrappedResponse =
  new SaveToSessionResponseWrapper(response, request, httpSession != null, context);
requestResponseHolder.setResponse(wrappedResponse);
```

You can find more information about this class here:

[HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/3.0.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/web/context/HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java)